# How to geolocate an alexa device in real time?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maps, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build a skill that would geolocate a device in realtime.

Say if a person staying at Germany i.e. his device address is added as Germany in the device but when tomorrow he travels to London then the skill must be able to locate him and say he is in London.

I have checked the Device ID API but with this API it seems the skill will always say that the person is in Germany even if he travels outside of it.

For my skill, the input would just be an invoke .

Any ideas?

Comment: In what language? Using which framework? Have you actually tried coding it? Why not edit adding what you have done do far?

Comment: Does the Alexa platform even support this?

Comment: My Echo doesn't have GPS or anything like that in it.  At best you could do a geo-location on the IP address.

Comment: Yes, you're right .. Alexa devices do not have GPS .. I tried calling Google Geolocation service but got to know it requires GPS details like cell tower, mobile carrier, homeMobileCountryCode, radioType, etc. Hence one possible way is to get the IP  and do a reverse lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexa devices do not have GPS .. I tried calling Google Geolocation service but got to know it requires GPS details like cell tower, mobile carrier, homeMobileCountryCode, radioType, etc. Hence one possible way is to get the IP and do a reverse lookup or I use Device Address API to read the address configured in my alexa device.